# How to keep Boolean tool "cutter" from showing in render or affecting physics?

Tags: rendering, modifiers, visibility

I'm New To Blender And I'm Trying To Use Boolean Tool (I have some 3d Modeling experience with other software), I have watched some tutorials but couldn't find my answer about Boolean Tool in blender.

Here is what I'm trying to do :

[image]
[image]

I want to use a torus to make a hole with the Boolean tool, but I don't want to keep the torus in my scene, I know I can hide it but when I'm trying to render or add physics it'll affect my scene.
Is there a way to remove it and still keep the Boolean cut?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Apply modifier :) ... Or you can keep it, but to exclude from rendering you have to also uncheck camera icon and exclude from sim I don't think you have to do something special, since you don't assign rigid body.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the boolean modifier to Cube (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) and then remove the torus.

Also you can manage the visibility in the viewport with the eye icon, or render visibility with the camera icon at the outliner.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The torus should not have any effect on physics so long as you don't add physics properties to it.

To hide it from the render, simply clock on the camera icon next to it in the outliner.  If the camera is an outline with an 'x' inside it, it means that the torus will have no part in the render.  It's disabled from render.

Likewise you can click the eye icon to hide it in the viewport, but another common practice is to go to its Display type to *wire* so that you can still see it to move it around if you have to adjust the position of the hole:

[image: Object properties showing Display as set to Wire]

The disadvantage of this approach over simply applying the modifier is that applying the modifier is simpler.  The advantage is that it's *non-destructive*.  That makes it easier to modify the model later if you need to move or enlarge the hole, or even change the radius of the torus.

It's worth learning to do, if you plan on using Booleans with any regularity, because a non-destructive workflow is very flexible.